# Extract a JSON property with an asterisk in the property name using get_json_object() in SparkSql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table in Databricks that has a column (called "properties") which contains JSON data. I've successfully used get_json_object() in a SparkSql notebook to retrieve properties from it like so:

```
%sql
select distinct_id, get_json_object(properties, "$.time")
from my_table
```

This works well. However, there are sub-properties in the properties column that have asterisks in their names, e.g. ***Plan**. Accessing these properties in the standard way, e.g. **$.*Plan** doesn't work, since * has special meaning for get_json_object(). I've tried accessing these properties using escape chars, like so:

```
%sql
select distinct_id, get_json_object(properties, "$.\*Plan")
from my_table
```

... along with alternative escapes, but to no avail. Is there a way to extract JSON sub-properties that can escape the asterisk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LATERAL VIEW` and `json_tuple` as a workaround.  It's not so fussy about special characters eg:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM my_table
  LATERAL VIEW json_tuple( properties, '*Plan' ) x
```

Or if you are wedded to using `get_json_object` you can clean up the string beforehand (although you have somewhat defeated the point of using JSON):

```
%sql
select 
  distinct_id, 
  get_json_object(replace(properties, '*', ''), '$.Plan' ) z
from my_table
```

I couldn't personally get any escaping methods to work ( eg \u0042 or \ ) but happy to be corrected.

Ideally, don't put such strange characters in your JSON in the first place.